# How to display cell info display (CID) on screen?

Tags: cellular-radio, system-info

Does Android OS have an option for showing **Cell Info Display** (Name of the cell Tower) on home screen ? (Without using external apps)

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to display this on the Home screen without 3rd party apps.

You can use this app called [CellID Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.its_here.cellidinfo) from Google Play Store, you may find [other apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=cellid&c=apps) that display this info too. The CellID Info doesn't say if it has a widget (i don't think it does) but some of the other ones might.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the solution i am looking for. I want the Cell ID info to be displayed on the home screen, not in an app. Like how it is shown on Nokia mobiles.

Comment: and you wont be able to do that without using an app. It isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Just download [OpenSignal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal&hl=en) from Play Store.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? _How/why_ does this app solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to read the Cell tower info since its one of the BroadCast messages. But it does not come up on screen automatically! It is possible to get this as notifications in SMS, once you enable Cell BroadCast messagess (CB) usually in the native SMS application settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cell Info Display](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.virtual.applets.cellinfodisplay) app available on Google Play.

> Cell info display will be useful to know about the locality information in case of any travel to new location.
>
> *Limitations*: This application works only if there is an Internet connectivity